# php and ajax autocomplete with multi-language support?

Tags: php, ajax

i just want to know how to implement  autocomplete with multi-language support like Google
i mean what do i have to change in the code and where?
and is there a free php and ajax autocomplete class that support multi-language?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "multi-language support" exactly. Automatic detection of browser language? Lookup databases in multiple languages? Please add more detail. Alsp, what code are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery autocomplete plugin you could use:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete

Not too sure about multi-language, though. You'd have to build that in yourself.